# I need to drag down an array formula using VBA and paste values but excel keeps crashing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to drag down an array formula for a range of cells and then copy/paste the respective values. However, my excel keeps crashing. Basically the formula goes to a specific row and then all the values are hard pasted into the worksheet. I am new to VBA so please feel free to dissect my code and give suggestions.

```
Dim lastRow1 As Long
lastRow1 = 37

'change i to whatever your starting row is. Cells(i, #), the # indicates the column index
For i = 3 To lastRow1
Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i, 6)
Cells(i, 6).FormulaArray = ""array formula"
Cells(i, 6).Copy
Cells(i, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: what is the array formula?  that is probably the issue.

Comment: I was able to perform this macro with the macro record function, so i don't think the array formula is the issue. I'm just trying to change my code without using the record function

Comment: `""array formula"`?

Comment: That's just a placeholder. I didn't bother putting the actually formula because it's irrelevant in my case. I'm just wondering if my code will copy a formula down and paste the values

Answer (score 0):

drag down:

```
   Range("A6").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "formula"
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A6:A" & lastRow1)
```

copy-paste values:

```
   Range("A6:A" & lastRow1).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

lastRow function (**lastRow1 = fLastRow** instead of lastRow1 = 37):

```
Function fLastRow() As Long
    fLastRow = 0
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
        fLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End If
End Function
```